# add_subdirectory error in CMake when installing Google Test

Tags: cmake, googletest, googlemock

When I run the `cmake ..` command while installing Google Test, the following error occurs:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_subdirectory):  
 add_subdirectory given source "googlemock" which is not an existing   
 directory.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

How do I solve this? These are the commands I was running beforehand:

1. When I first used the `cmake ..` command, it failed with `'nmake' '-?'` as the output
2. Then I tried running `cmake . -G "MinGW Makefiles"`, and received the `add-subdirectory` error above
3. After that, when I tried the `cmake ..` command again, the same error occurs

Screenshots of the errors:

[image: cmake ..]

[image: cmake . -G "MinGW Makefiles"]

[image: cmake ..]

Comment: Looks like you have deleted the `googlemock` directory after cloning [that repo](https://github.com/google/googletest). Unless explicitly stated, building a project from a repository requires all files in that repository.